# shared_ptrs and memory leaks

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks

I had a project to do in C++ (moreover, I had to use some stuff from C++11, specifically: custom iterators, smart pointers and chrono) which constructs suffix tree for specific string. When it comes down to constructing a tree, I think I did a good job - I have a proper tree, construction times and search times are looking rather good and there's not a single problem with this. However, I know I messed up with my TNode struct - I didn't use weak_ptrs, therefore in my tree class I had to build up hugeass destructor walking on every node and forcibly erasing any connections.

Anyway, I used Deleaker to check for possible memory leaks. There were none for "abracadabra" word. Unfortunately, it found some leaks for "lorem ipsum (...)". Most of them are linked with creating new nodes and I fail to understand where my problem is. I simply don't get it - it appears that every node is destructed when program is ending. Where did I make mistake?

Node.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <Windows.h>

#define INF 1<<30

struct TNode : public std::enable_shared_from_this<TNode>{
    long int indexStart;
    long int indexEnd;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<TNode>> children;
    std::shared_ptr<TNode> suffixLink;
    int count;
    TNode(long int pIndexStart, int pCount) {
        indexStart = pIndexStart;
        indexEnd = INF;
        children.clear();
        suffixLink = nullptr;
        count = pCount;
    }
    ~TNode() {
        //OutputDebugString(L"node dies\n");
    }
    int EdgeLength(long int pos) {
        return min(indexEnd, pos+1) - indexStart;
    }
};
```

tree.h

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include "IChildIterator.h"
#include "Node.h"

class CTree
{
public:
    CTree();
    ~CTree();
    void LoadString(std::string* newString);
    void CreateTree();
    bool FindPhrase(std::string* toFind);
    void PrintSuffix(std::vector<long> indexes);
    std::shared_ptr<TNode> GetRoot();

private:
    std::shared_ptr<TNode>  root;
    std::shared_ptr<TNode>  activeNode;
    long int                activeEdge;
    long int                activeLength;
    std::string*            string;
    std::shared_ptr<TNode>  lastAddedNode;
    long int                position;
    long int                remainder;
    int                     count;

    void AddSuffixLink(std::shared_ptr<TNode> node);
    bool WalkDown(std::shared_ptr<TNode> node);
    void ExtendTree();
    char GetActiveEdge();
};
```

tree.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Tree.h"


CTree::CTree()
{
    std::shared_ptr<TNode> nowy(new TNode(-1, -1));
    root = activeNode = nowy;
    activeEdge = activeLength = 0;
    lastAddedNode = nowy;
    position = -1;
    remainder = 0;
    count = 0;
    string = nullptr;
}


CTree::~CTree()
{
    if (string) {
        delete string;
    }
    std::vector<IChildIterator> iterstack;
    iterstack.resize(0);
    IChildIterator child(root, true);
    while (true) {
        if (0 == (*child)->children.size()) {
            if (iterstack.size() == 0)
                break;
            child = iterstack.back();
            iterstack.pop_back();
            (*child)->children.erase((*child)->children.begin());
            child++;
            continue;
        }
        if ((*child)->children.front()->indexEnd != INF) {
            iterstack.push_back(child);
            child = IChildIterator(*child);
            continue;
        }
        std::shared_ptr<TNode> temp = (*child)->children.front();
        if (temp->suffixLink) temp->suffixLink = nullptr;
        (*child)->children.erase((*child)->children.begin());
    }

    OutputDebugString(L"tree dies\n");
}

void CTree::LoadString(std::string* newString)
{
    string = new std::string(*newString);
}

void CTree::CreateTree()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < string->size(); i++) {
        ExtendTree();
    }
}

std::shared_ptr<TNode> CTree::GetRoot()
{
    return root;
}

void CTree::AddSuffixLink(std::shared_ptr<TNode> node)
{
    if (lastAddedNode) lastAddedNode->suffixLink = node;
    lastAddedNode = node->shared_from_this();
}

bool CTree::WalkDown(std::shared_ptr<TNode> node)
{
    if (activeLength >= node->EdgeLength(position)) {
        activeEdge += node->EdgeLength(position);
        activeLength -= node->EdgeLength(position);
        activeNode = node;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void CTree::ExtendTree()
{
    ++position;
    lastAddedNode = nullptr;
    remainder++;
    while (remainder > 0) {
        if (activeLength == 0) activeEdge = position;
        std::shared_ptr<TNode> selected = nullptr;
        for each (std::shared_ptr<TNode> child in activeNode->children) {
            if (string->at(child->indexStart) == GetActiveEdge()) {
                selected = child;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!selected) {
            std::shared_ptr<TNode> newLeaf(new TNode(position, count++));
            activeNode->children.push_back(newLeaf);
            AddSuffixLink(activeNode);
        }
        else {
            if (WalkDown(selected)) continue;
            if (string->at(selected->indexStart + activeLength) == string->at(position)) {
                activeLength++;
                AddSuffixLink(activeNode);
                break;
            }
            //split
            if (selected->children.size() > 0) {
                long lastStart = selected->indexStart;
                selected->indexStart = selected->indexStart + activeLength;
                std::shared_ptr<TNode> newNode(new TNode(lastStart, count++));
                newNode->indexEnd = selected->indexStart;
                newNode->children.push_back(selected);
                std::shared_ptr<TNode> yetAnotherNewLeaf(new TNode(position, count++));
                newNode->children.push_back(yetAnotherNewLeaf);
                std::vector<std::shared_ptr<TNode>>::iterator iter;
                iter = activeNode->children.begin();
                while (true) {
                    if (*iter == selected) {
                        activeNode->children.insert(iter, newNode);
                        iter = activeNode->children.begin();
                        while (true) {
                            if (*iter == selected) {
                                activeNode->children.erase(iter);
                                break;
                            }
                            iter++;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    iter++;
                }
                AddSuffixLink(newNode);
            }
            else {
                selected->indexEnd = selected->indexStart + activeLength;
                std::shared_ptr<TNode> newLeaf(new TNode(selected->indexEnd, count++));
                selected->children.push_back(newLeaf);
                std::shared_ptr<TNode> yetAnotherNewLeaf(new TNode(position, count++));
                selected->children.push_back(yetAnotherNewLeaf);
                AddSuffixLink(selected);
            }
        }
        remainder--;
        if (activeNode == root && activeLength > 0) {
            activeLength--;
            activeEdge = position - remainder + 1;
        }
        else {
            if (activeNode->suffixLink) {
                activeNode = activeNode->suffixLink;
            }
            else {
                activeNode = root;
            }
        }
    }
}

char CTree::GetActiveEdge()
{
    return string->at(activeEdge);
}
```

Memory leaks:

- during creation of every new node in ExtendTree() method
- tree constructor
- on line

  > iter = activeNode->children.begin();

I'd be grateful for any kind of tip how to fix this.

Comment: `string = new std::string(*newString);`  With all of your usage of smart pointers, you need to do or have something like this?  I can easily create a `main` program that leaks memory, just given that one line.

Comment: TLDR; Never use shared_ptr referencing to childs and parents. Either make the child pointers or the parent pointers a weak_ptr (or raw pointer) If not you have circular references, leading to a memory leak.

Comment: [OT] I see you did not implement a copy constructor.  Since you did not if you copy a `CTree` the copy will refer the the original so anything you do to the copy happens to the original.  Not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: Why is `CTree::string` even a pointer?

Comment: Mostly my fault, I started to use normal pointer when I wrote class and few methods, by the time I noticed it it was **bit** too late and I decided to leave it as it is. Thanks for noticing that though. @NathanOliver I didn't need copy constructor, since I plan to use only a single instance of tree at the time.

Comment: @n4zArh If you do not want copies, express that: `T(const T&) = delete` and `T& operator = (const T&) = delete` (pre c++11 make these private)

Answer (score 1):

There's a potential leak when calling `LoadString`:

```
void CTree::LoadString(std::string* newString)
{
    string = new std::string(*newString);
}
```

This function does not delete previously allocated `string`.

Your method for creating `shared_ptr` objects is also odd. This shouldn't necessarily cause memory leaks but it's very strange to behold. You are, for example, doing this:

```
std::shared_ptr<TNode> newLeaf(new TNode(position, count++));
```

When you should be doing this:

```
std::shared_ptr<TNode> newLeaf = std::make_shared<TNode>(position, count++)
```

Comment: While `std::make_shared` is the *preferred* method of creating `shared_ptr`s, it is not incorrect to do it manually. Specifically, using `make_shared` allocates the block for the refcount along with the block for the object, whereas calling the constructor manually will allocate the refcount on a separate block. This is important because whatever block the refcount is on will stay alive as long as any `weak_ptr`s pointing at the block are still alive.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I fixed my LoadString to have a check if there's a string and to delete it if there is some of them (however I use this method once, so there was no leak there). Also, changed the way I create shared_ptr - it was only one I knew :) unfortunately it did not help with memory leaks.

Comment: On the note of memory leaks, one of the reasons that `make_shared` and `make_unique` are preferred is that they ensure that the allocation is owned by the time the `make_` function returns. Calling `new` manually can leak if it is done as one of several parameters to a function, the others of which might throw. The order that parameters are evaluated is implementation-specific, so a throw there would lead to a leak.